# C Program exe file defined as a Trojan:Win32 Virus. How to solve this problem?

Tags: c, trojan

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr4GB.png)

When I run a basic C code in VS Code then windows defender called it a Trojan:Win32. It makes the file removed. It really makes difficulties. So, what should I do now?

I reinstall the mingw compiler for it, but it goes the same things again and again. Now I want to solve this problem but couldn't get any solution.....

Comment: Build either a release version or if 32-bit, change to 64-bit or vice-versa.  Alternatively, change the compilation model from MDd to MTd or even just MD or MT.

Comment: The solution is to uninstall all so-called "anti-virus" bloatware. Why would you have an anti-virus program when it has literally all the characteristics of a virus? Lag down your computer, block you from using it like intended, pretend that it is something which is it not, force you to pay a ransom to keep using your computer etc etc. I really don't see much of a difference at all between viruses and "anti-viruses", they both seek to do you harm. At least a virus is honest about it though.

Comment: My development directory on my drive is *always* excluded from windows defender scanning while I am developing,  I too have been bugged many times by false positives by windows defender during development.  Also, it has halted me many, many times from running the compiled executable while it does a qwk scan.  Excluding a directory from Defender scan is *very* easy and you can websearch it if needed. If -- after your development of a program is complete, or near complete -- *then* is the time to investigate why it's getting flagged by Defender.

Comment: @Lundin: I acknowledge having used a PC without any antivirus software for years without any problem. But as I knew the system was rather vulnerable I avoided any dangerous task like testing any unknown software (and used my corporate system having a well known anti-virus for that...). But I would never advise a casual user not to install an anti-virus on a familial machine... Furthermore, you can find a number of free (in the sense of free beer, not free software) yet acceptable quality antivirus softwares...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Quality placebo, you mean. I've used computers for more than 30 years, mostly without any anti-virus. During that time I've gotten some minor malware incidents 2 times. One which I could fix myself by manually removing it, one which I could fix by reinstalling Windows. Keeping backups is what's important, but I never even had to use one because of malware. At work I've seen the company I work for getting hit by viruses several times though - they always had anti-virus and it never did them any good. Annoying, but since every company keeps backups, no big deal.

Comment: @Lundin: I should not say that you are a *casual user* ;-)

Comment: @SergeBallesta Maybe not, but programmers are kind of expected to have basic computer knowledge such as "do not open e-mail strange e-mail attachments" and "do not download executables from fishy sites"... not doing so gets you very far.

Answer (score 1):

If Windows Defender is flagging your compiled C code as a Trojan, it’s likely a false positive. This can happen when antivirus programs mistakenly identify safe files as malicious.

Here are a few steps you can take to address the issue:

1. Add your build directory to the exclusion list of Windows Defender.
   This can prevent it from scanning and removing your compiled executable. You can find this setting in Windows Security under “Virus & threat protection” -> “Manage settings” -> “Add or remove exclusions.”
2. You can disable Windows Defender (only if absolutely necessary, as it may pose risks to your computer by leaving it vulnerable to other potential threats)

Comment: Solution 1 is the way to go. Solution 2 is too dangerous IMHO.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta Yep, I know. So I'm not recommending choosing solution 2, unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> Build either a release version or if 32-bit, change to 64-bit or vice-versa. Alternatively, change the compilation model from MDd to MTd or even just MD or MT.

–
cup